# Call controller from click within an iframe with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to bind an event to an iframe so that no matter where in the iframe is clicked, the event fires a function in the angular controller.  I am trying to do this with just the jquery lite that ships with angular, or with pure javascript, whichever solution I happen across first.

I have been trying variations on this but not having any luck:

```
angular.element('iframe').contents().find('html').bind('click', function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Here is one with full jquery i can deal with a solution using the entire jquery library if necessary http://plnkr.co/edit/wNUEbteVkRa0ZotQEY2w?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't go looking for elements out of the blue like normal jquery apps. you got to use a directive.

look here : [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VgKv8GYQBWYyff8s4KyA?p=preview)

In myDirective, i use the iframe element to do what you wanted:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){

  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attributes){
      element.contents().find('html').bind('click', function () {
           alert("hello");
       });
    }
  };

});
```

You should also take some steps to ensure that the 'element' in the link function is an iframe.

Comment: Thanks this does work in plnkr but not in my app unfortunately so I am guessing there is something blocking the click even in what is being loaded in the iframe